# Can I reduce elif instructions in my python code?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I'm currently learning python and I was wondering whether I could reduce elif instructions in my code.

Here's a problem description:

SUMMER OF '69: Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.

summer_69([1, 3, 5]) --> 9

summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9

summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]) --> 14

And here's my proposition:

```py
def summer_69(arr):
    
        sum = 0
        alert = 0
    
    for x in arr:
    
            if x != 6 and alert == 0:
                sum = sum + x
    
            elif x == 6:
                alert = 1
        
            elif x == 9:
                alert = 0
        
            elif alert == 1:
                pass
    
    
        print(sum)
```

Comment: Your code looks malformatted. Is the indentation correct?

Comment: The CodeReview StackExchange is a better place for general code review. You definitely _could_, by doing some math and using some functions like filter. But your current code is readable and not very long.

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: What's the point of your `elif alert == 1:` `pass`, why did you add that?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to avoiding any use of `elif` is to create an iterator from the input sequence, so that within a `for` loop that iterates over the iterator and summing the numbers, you can use a `while` loop when encountering a `6` to skip numbers by consuming the iterator until the iterator returns a `9`:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    seq = iter(arr)
    for i in seq:
        if i == 6:
            while next(seq) != 9:
                pass
        else:
            total += i
    return total
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/VirtualGuiltyRatio

You can also go full-blown `itertools`:

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    seq = iter(arr)
    while True:
        total += sum(takewhile((6).__ne__, seq))
        try:
            next(dropwhile((9).__ne__, seq))
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return total
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/RemorsefulOutlandishIntroductory

Answer (score 0):

Is it cheating to use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) to avoid the need for `elif`? This coding style will be familiar to Verilog coders, but might not be very Pythonic:

```
sum = 0
alert = False
for x in arr:
    if alert:
        if x == 9:
            alert = False
        continue
    
    if x == 6:
        alert = True
        continue
    sum += x
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only three things that you might do with each number: start skipping, stop skipping, or add to the total.  That means three different conditions (not four) as long as you arrange them right:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    skip = False
    for x in arr:
        if x == 6:
            skip = True
        elif x == 9 and skip:
            skip = False
        elif not skip:
            total += x
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let Python do the work for you:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    it = iter(arr)
    total = 0
    for x in it:
        if x == 6:
            9 in it
        else:
            total += x
    print(total)
```

Whenever you see a `6`, the `9 in it` finds its corresponding `9` and leaves the iterator at the position after it.

Or with a generator expression and the `sum` function:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    it = iter(arr)
    print(sum(
        x for x in it
        if x != 6 or 9 not in it
    ))
```

That `if` clause could alternatively be written as `if not (x == 6 and 9 in it)`.

Answer (score -1):

this code must work

```
def summer_69(arr):
    sum = 0
    alert = 0

    for x in arr:

        if x == 9 :
            alart=0
            continue
        elif x==6 or alart==1:
            alart=1
            continue

        sum = sum + x



    print(sum)
```